# Prevent numpy.linalg.norm method from cropping values to the inputs dtype min/max

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have these 2 NumPy arrays for example:
`a = np.array([[0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8) b = np.array([[130, 130, 130],[254, 254, 254]], dtype=np.uint8)`

and when I run np.linalg.norm() to calculate the euclidean distance between points a and b:
`np.linalg.norm((a-b), axis=1)`
it returns [218.2, 3.4] which would make sense for the first returned value but the second value is only 3.4, which should be higher. It looks like since 254 is close to the int limit for unsigned 8 bit integers, and since numpy doesn't clamp its arrays, its basically calculating the distance between 254 and one value over the limit which is just 2 away. Is there a way to get it to calculate the distance without overflowing so getting the distance between [0, 0, 0] and [254, 254, 254] returns about 439.9 and not 3.4. When I change both arrays dtypes to int16 obviously it fixes the problem since the int16 limit is higher. However, I would rather use uint8s since I'm working with image data and it is less memory.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `norm`. Your problem is happening when you try to do `a-b`.

Comment: The 218.2 value is also wrong - it should be about 225, not 218.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([[130, 130, 130],[254, 254, 254]], dtype=np.uint8)
print(np.linalg.norm(np.maximum(a,b)-np.minimum(a,b),  axis=1))
```